# Target Dynamically Created Divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic

I dynamically create a number of divs using javascript based on the number of sections in an external text file. The divs are initially populated with a graph but I'd like to be able to individually toggle the divs over to the raw data that was used to build each graph.

If the text file has 25 sections and creates 25 divs, how do I 'select' say, the 15th div to toggle to the alternate view?

http://jsfiddle.net/EwNRJ/2357/ - demo of a manual solution and framework of the dynamic solution

```
for (var i = 5; i < count+1; i++) {
    new_divs += '<button class="div' + count + '_toggle">toggle ' + count + '</button>;
    new_divs += '<div id="div' + count + '_main" class="main" ></div>';
    new_divs += '<div id="div' + count + '_alt" class="alt" ></div>';
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "select" - access via code (`$('container div').get(index);`) or be able to click to then move to the next view (use a delegated event listener attached to the container)?

Comment: I mean access via code so that I can hide that specific div and show the one replacing it.

`$("div1_toggle_btn").click(function() {
     $("div1_graph").hide();
     $("div1_raw").show();
}`

Comment: I've just realised you added a bit of code into your comment. This is different to what the question asks. Can you add some sample HTML to show the structure of the graph, raw, and toggle button divs. There is probably a much cleaner solution than targeting the nth div as the question suggests in its current form.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I've linked a jsfiddle on the original comment.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery to select all of the child elements `$('.container .child')`, and then you can use the [`eq()` function](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) to get the nth element. Note that the arrays are zero-indexed, so the fifth element is element 4.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // get 5th element (remember arrays are zero-indexed/start at 0)
  var $fifth = $('.container .child').eq(4);
  
  // show the fifth element has been selected by setting color to red
  $fifth.css({color: 'red'});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">1</div>
  <div class="child">2</div>
  <div class="child">3</div>
  <div class="child">4</div>
  <div class="child">5</div>
  <div class="child">6</div>
  <div class="child">7</div>
  <div class="child">8</div>
</div>
```